# 555 timer to drive IRFP460

Tags: mosfet, 555, mosfet-driver

I am trying to make a Slayer exciter using a MOSFET.

[image]
<sup>From [here](http://www.electroboom.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/High-Power-Slayer.jpg).</sup>

It uses these parts

- R1 = 2 Ω
- R2 >= 22 kΩ
- D2 = 1N4148, or 1N400x (x is a number)
- U1 = [MIC4452](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MIC4452)
- Q1 = [2SK2542](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/408/2SK2542_datasheet_en_20100413-738902.pdf)

I don't have a MIC4452 to drive the MOSFET.

Can a NE555 run a MOSFET? How would I do that? Maybe there is another way without using a gate driver?

Comment: The Mosfet type of transistor needs to have a certain voltage at its gate in order to work,which is bigger than the gate-source threshold voltage.In your case that is 4V(check datasheet).

Comment: You should add more details about the design.Look on the site and put some details in your question.I don't really know what is the exact purpose of the resistor-diode network before U1.If it's just for biasing the driver,you can leave them out,connect the battery to 555,trigger connected to - and output to the gate of the MOSFET

Comment: I agree with Daniel Tork. For a fast switching of power MOSFETs, you also need a device which can output a sufficiently high current in the gate. You should use a MOSFET driver (e.g. PM8851, IR2113, ...)

Comment: I would try. Turning a MOSFET is "just charging it's input capacitance". Basically if you drive a MOSFET with low current it will take longer to turn on, which means higher switching losses (it gets hot). On the other hand, if you drive it too hard, it makes a lot of noise and you get overshoot everywhere(because of the very high dv/dt). This is what R1 is for, to tune "how fast" you turn it on. Your 555 wouldn't be as low impedance as a proper driver, in that case just make R1 low, or remove it altogether.  Then just keep an eye on the transistor temp in case it gets too hot. Don't be afraid!

Comment: You need a snubber across your primary to discharge the leakage inductance, otherwise your transistor will last exactly one switching event. Since this is essentially a flyback, I would suggest you search for "RCD snubber"

Answer (score 0):

You're can probably make this work. You will need to use to use a CMOS 555 and operate it from a voltage between 12-15 Vdc. You will also need to buffer the output with a complimentary pair of beefy transistors such as 2n4401 and 2n4403.

This buffer is extremely simple - feed both bases from the 555,both emitters feed the MOSFET.  The collector of the NPN transistor connects to the 555 V+12 pin, the collector of the PNP transistor connects to ground.

You may need to add a low-value resistor in series with the gate of the MOSFET to reduce the chance of parasitic oscillation. Start with 10 Ohms and physically place the resistor as close to the MOSFET as possible.

This should give you very fast edges at the gate of the MOSFET.

Comment: Why must the gate voltage be so high?Why not 6-9V?

Comment: Im not sure how to wire this up? Can I get a circuit diagram thats easy to understand? I am very new to 555 timers and using mosfets. :)

Comment: Can I use two tip31c transistors? I don't have a pnp transistor :(

Comment: Also NE555 same as CMOS 555?

Comment: I would also add a flyback diode across the primary of T1, unless Q1 already has a diode between source and drain.

Comment: This is actually a dangerous idea if you have no deadtime, you might create shoot through between your transistors.

Comment: @Andrés: Run a simulation using LTSpice or similar.  You will see that there is no possibility of what you call Shoot Through with the transistors.  This is because they are both Emitter Followers - voltage gain is (slightly) less than unity.